# Generis method got error cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, generics

I try to make the generic method for other class. But I got a error 
`cannot be referenced from a static context`

How to do the generics method for `GetInstance`

```
public class Instance<T> {

    private static final Instance<?> mInstance = new Instance<>(null);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Instance<T> GetInstance() { //Got error
        // Make generic static instance.
        // Strategy used similar to Collections.emptyList() implementation
        return (Instance<T>) mInstance; //Got Error
    }

    protected Instance(Context context) {

    }
}
```

```
 public static DataController GetDataController(@Nullable  Context context) {
    DataController dataController = (DataController) DataController.GetInstance();
    if(dataController == null) {
        return new DataController(context);
    }

    return dataController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's the ancient druid magic

```
public static <T> Instance<T> GetInstance() {
    return (Instance<T>) mInstance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply.

Comment: @ManLokWong, L.Spillner answer is more info, mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are poperty of the class rather than of an instance of the class and therefore the generic of the class cannot be referenced.

However you can still create a generic method by adding a type reference directly to the method:

```
public static <T> Instance<T> GetInstance() {...}
```

And even bound it:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Instance<T> GetInstance() {...}
```

However to call such a method you maybe need to pass the type argument if the compiler can't infer it by itself:

```
Instance.<Integer> GetInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply.